# How debbuging remote VPN Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I work with Adroid Studio remote by VPN, the server with the IDE is in the work, and the client with the device is in my home.

Instead of use the Emulator, and use the device how can debbuging remote Server (Android Studio) to the Client (My home device) ?

[image]